# Процесс nodeJS "замирает"

Tags: node.js

Есть проект на nodejs. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не знаю, как решить.
Проект представляет собой бэк, который принимает от пользователей запросы, ходит в базу данных Oracle, так же реализовано кэширование запросов от БД(Данные в БД обновляются раз в N часов, поэтому нет смысла по одному и тому же запросу ходить БД, быстрее ответ просто вернуть из КЭШа).

Так же есть функция, которая запускается раз в некоторое время и проверяет состояние КЭШа(сортирует его, удаляет старое, если есть изменения в БД, обновляет данные и т.д.)

Взаимодействие с пользователями идет по сокету.

В случае, когда количество элементов в кэше достигает 300+ при нагрузке примерно в 5-7 запросов в секунду, когда, предположительно, запускается обновление кэша, процесс nodejs иногда "замирает".
Нагрузка на CPU примерно 13%, RAM не меняется(+/- 10Кб из 600Мб - погрешность вычислений). Вывод console.log() останавливается, запись логов так же, на все запросы по сокету или ресту сервер не отвечает. Молчит.

Ошибка плавающая. На нагрузочном тестировании, давали нагрузку в 400-500 запросов в минуту, количество элементов в кэше достигало более 13000 элементов, стабильно работает и очистка и обновление данных... но в какой то момент может все просто замереть...

После замирания, сам процесс очухивается в разное время(5-7-45 мин) и может вывести в лог несколько строчек и опять замирает. Может ошибка вообще не случиться за все время теста(24 часа).

Кто знает, как можно "поймать" эту ошибку? Узнать, чем в этот момент занят event loop и занят ли он? Ведь что то процесс непрерывно делает на 13% CPU(8 потоков/ядер на серверах)
Список зависимостей из package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.18",
    "node-worker-threads-pool": "^1.5.0",
    "oracledb": "^5.2.0",
    "p-queue": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.0",
    "ws": "^7.4.2"
},
```

`node -v` -> 14.17.4

Циклов вида forEach, map крайне мало и используются только на маленьких массивах(до 10 элементов).

Вся обработка больших данных вынесена в worker_threads с использованием пакета node-worker-threads-pool(Организация пула воркеров).

Внутри организованы очереди по обработчикам(пакет p-queue), что бы не допускать большого количества запросов. На все виды действий установлен лимит выполнения, остальные ждут свое очереди.

Так же в описании пакета oracledb есть упоминание о настройке [UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-162-connections-threads-and-parallelism), я ее не менял. Это может быть причиной "остановки" процессов, если допустим oracledb забило все обработчики и не отпускает их(Допустим БД проблема или ошибка в коде, что я ожидаю разблокировки объекта...)?

Проекту больше года, первую такую ошибку словил 2 месяца назад.

Прошу любой помощи и советов, как понять, что происходит? Почему останавливается обработка всего и вся...

Comment: Попробуйте записать профайл , возможно он натолкнет на что-то https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Comment: 13% на восьмиядерном проце?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, на 8 ядрах 13%(+/- 1 %). Платформа Windows 10. На Linux нагрузки на CPU в этот момент нет. падает в 0. График потребления памяти вычерчивает ровную горизонтальную линию...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась путем исправления ошибки в коде на СУБД Oracle а так же увеличение количества UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE

> UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE отвечает за количество обработчиков ввода/вывода. По умолчанию их 4. Т.е. одновременно node.js может обрабатывать не более 4-х операций ввода/вывода.

Когда на БД возникает блокировка, то пакет oracledb открывает 4 соединения к БД и ждет ответа. Остальные операции становятся не возможными, т.к. все обработчики заняты.

Решение было таким:

1. Было исправлено обновление таблицы, которое приводило к блокировкам записей
2. Количество UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE было установлено в значение превышающее максимальное количество соединений с БД, что бы сам процесс node.js мог продолжать работу дальше.

На *nix

```
UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=128 node
```

При старте приложения

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=128
```

На win
cmd

```
SET UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=128 && node index.js
```

powerShell

```
$env:UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 128 && node my-file-to-run.js
```

UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE отвечает только за ввод/вывод и никак не связан с ядрами на сервере.

Количество UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE должно быть больше чем возможное использование событий ввода/вывода приложения.

Comment: Ситуация улучшилась, однако ошибка стала проявляться при запросах, которые долго ждут выполнения(тыжелый запрос в БД). [Продолжение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501611/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-node-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%91%d0%94)